# Question about DP in Android

Tags: android, fill-parent

Let's say I prefer using "dp" rather than "fill_parent" or "wrap_content", what would be the appropriate number to use in order to fill the screen with a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends of the screen and of its density. Check [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to learn more about that.

(This may lead you to reconsider using `fill_parent` / `wrap_content` by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you "prefer" this? Precise dp values for `layout_width`/`layout_height` are one tool alongside `match_parent` and `wrap_content` and building a nice UI will usually involve all three. Which one is appropriate for each dimension of any given View is situational and `match_parent`'s entire reason for existence is to match the size of a View's container, in your case the screen.

(* `match_parent` is the newer name for `fill_parent`.)